# Facebook account which isn't mine

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My facebook is sorted like this

```
- (IBAction)fb:(id)sender {

  NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://notes/Nike"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"]]; }
}
```

The problem is, I have an account on facebook application but I wanted it to go to another fb account which is the "Nike" .. it's not!

I checked before this and tried them all, no use

> ```
> fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile
>
> fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list
>
> fb://notifications – Open Facebook app to the notifications list
>
> fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed
>
> fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page
>
> fb://requests – Open Facebook app to the Requests list
>
> fb://notes – Open Facebook app to the Notes page
>
> fb://albums – Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list
> ```

Can anybody help?

EDITED
ADDED

```
- (IBAction)fb:(id)sender {

    NSURL *fbURLWeb = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/nike"];
    NSURL *fbURLId = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"fb://profile/15087023444"];

    // Check if FB app is installed
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbURLId]) {
        // If the FB app is installed
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbURLId];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbURLWeb];
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you try like this `[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://Nike/notes"];`

Comment: Do you have FB App installed? when FB app is not installed, your code is redirecting your app to `facebook.com`, not to the profile named nike.

Comment: Yes, I have it installed and how can I change it to a profile named Nike?

Comment: Why are you forming the url like `notes/Nike`? That does not seem right. Are you trying to open notes of profile named nike? Also, Are you sure that user's notes are public?

Comment: I am trying it to go when I tick on the link to https://www.facebook.com/nike/?fref=ts

Comment: Try `fb://profile/nike` for that. That page does not have any notes if I am correct.  And change the else condition url to `m.facebook.com/nike`.

Comment: It also didn't work :(

Comment: I found it, it's added to the the first and I needed http://findmyfbid.com/ as well